# Ruby partial word match

Tags: ruby, cpu-word, expression, match, partial

I need help finding a partial word match. It should return words that match three consecutive letters to the target. For example:

```
WORDS = ["born", "port" ,"cort", "mort"]
find_match("corn", WORDS)  =>  returns  ["born", "cort"]
```

should find partial matches for `"corn"`. And "b **orn** ", and " **cor** t" match.

Regular expressions may not be the best to solve such problem. If you have other ideas, feel free to share.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to build an array of substrings:

```
'corn'.chars.each_cons(3).map(&:join)
# ['cor', 'orn']
```

Then [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to convert the array to a single regex:

```
re = Regexp.union('corn'.chars.each_cons(3).map(&:join))
```

Then you can match `re` against the array elements:

```
WORDS.select { |w| w =~ re }
```

Generalizing:

```
def find_match(word, words)
    re = Regexp.union(word.chars.each_cons(3).map(&:join))
    words.select { |w| w =~ re }
end
```

I'm sure there are lots of variations on that general theme. For example, you could use the `match_str` form of [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) instead of a regex and I'm sure there are lots of different ways to pull out all the substrings of length 3.

Comment: @Stefan: Nice. I forget about `grep` a lot.

Comment: Thanks, mu.  So many things here that are new-to-me, plus @Stefan's reminder about grep.  I didn't know about either each_con or Regexp.union.  Very useful.  I'll have to look into Regexp's methods more thoroughly.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: The Enumerable docs (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) are necessary reading for anyone doing Ruby. Then you have to bounce between reading the Enumerable interface and thinking in a shell-pipeline/functional manner for awhile and eventually it becomes second nature. Consulting the docs often also helps keep you familiar with what's available (as does answering questions around here :). Looks like you're almost a neighbor too.

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex solution:

```
WORDS = ["born", "port" ,"cort", "mort"]

def find_match(w)
  threes = (0..w.size-3).reduce([]) {|arr, i| arr << w[i,3]}
  WORDS.select {|w| threes.select {|s| w.include?(s)}.any?}
end

find_match("corn")   # => ["born", "cort"] 
find_match("cavort") # => ["port", "cort", "mort"]   
find_match("heart")  # => []
```

- First compute `threes`, an array of all substrings of `w` that are of length three.  If `w = snort`, this would be `['sno', 'nor', 'ort']`, where `w[0,3] = 'sno'`, `w[1,3] = 'nor'` and `w[2,3] = 'ort'`.
- Next, select the words in `WORDS` that have a substring that matches at least on of the strings in `threes`.

There are of course many variants of this, such as:

```
threes = []; (threes << w[0,3]; w.slice!(0)) while w.size > 2
```

For the second line above, I initially tried

```
threes.reduce([]) {|arr1, s| arr1 += WORDS.select {|w| w.include?(s)}}
```

but that was problematic because a word in `WORDS` might match more than one 3-character substring of `w`, in which case it would be included in `arr1` once for each match.